# Tomcat shutdown.sh Could not contact localhost: 28005

Tags: tomcat

In the Linux Env , when I run shutdown.sh in the tomcat folder, here is an exception : java.net.ConnectionException: Connection refused. Then the process can be killed. But I don't know why here is the problem of the exception.

EVERE: Could not contact localhost:28005. Tomcat may not be running.

In the conf/server.xml , here are code :

```
<Server port="28005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
```

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stopServer(Catalina.java:450)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.stopServer(Bootstrap.java:398)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)

The stop command failed. Attempting to signal the process to stop through OS signal.
```

Hope no exception when I shut down tomcat

Comment: I'd check the ports tomcat is listening on when it's running, for instance with `netstat -plutan | grep <tomcat_pid>`. You should look for a Local Adress ending with `:28005`. If there is none, or if the IP isn't either `127.0.0.1` (localhost) or `0.0.0.0` (any address) that would explain why you get this error

Comment: It's in the Linux server not localhost. When I run command , it returns : tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:28005             0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      5669/java

Comment: I meant the linux server's localhost interface, I assume all the actions you're taking are on the server? Anyway nothing wrong with what you replied, the tomcat is correctly listening on its shutdown port. It's listening on (the server's) localhost though, so if you're trying to do remote management that might explain why it fails. I'm not very familiar with Tomcat so I hope what I'm saying makes sense.

Comment: Most probably, the shutdown port was not opened yet when you issued the stop command. This can happen if you have a slow starting application, because if you have an app  in the `webapp` folder, the server and the app start together. And the shutdown port is opend only after th elifecycle listeners of teh server complete successfully, but as the pre-deployed app starts together with the server it can prevent it from opening the shutdown port. Stupid, but that's how it works.

Answer (score 0):

In my side , this problem is the tomcat server has been killed , and my tomcat package is not completed. I copied tomcat from production server , everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**

Running `ps -aux | grep tomcat` will give you the PID of Tomcat, i.e.:

```
root      3127  0.0  0.0   5960   120 pts/0    T    14:14   0:00 tail -f /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out

root      3636  0.0  0.0   5960   112 pts/0    T    14:19   0:00 tail -f /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out

root      4936  0.0  0.0   5960   484 pts/2    T    14:50   0:00 tail -f /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out

root      5241  0.0  0.0  10472   920 pts/2    S+   15:02   0:00 grep --color=auto tomcat
```

**Step 2:**

Running `kill -9 3127` (`3127` being the PID found above) will kill the process. Repeat this command for other PIDs as necessary.

**Step 3:**

Restart your server by running `./startup.sh`